# Newest symfony installer vs composer

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'd like to know whats the difference when creating new symfony project with new symfony installer that has appeared last time and old-way composer.

I've installed latest version of symfony (2.6.1) with both, and result was different, for example when I install symfony with composer, i get .gitignore file.
When I install with new symfony installer script, gitignore is missing.

Here is amount of catalogs and files in fresh project:

```
symfony installer:                      1498 directories, 7136 files
symfony installer + composer update:    1571 directories, 7749 files
composer create-project:                1615 directories, 7905 files
```

I suppose I'll stick to old way - composer, since new installer seems to be bugged or at least not complete yet, however I'd like to understand more on this topic, whats the difference, is it safe to use new installer etc?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Leggendario already explained, the installer downloads the dist files from the website (a `.tar.gz` or `.zip` file). This speeds up the installation process quite a bit.

However, when building the dist files, symfony.com uses a custom build script which removes some files and changes some things. On the other hand, composer simply downloads the repository for you.

The main differences:

- Composer downloads the latest dependencies (as Leggendario pointed out), while the build script contains the latest files at the moment of building.
- Composer uses the dev versions and thus uses `git clone` to download the packages. The build script uses only stable packages, which will make Composer use the dist version. Some packages remove test and doc files from their dist files.
- Composer contains all project related information, like a `.gitignore`. The build script previously assumed the person installing it didn't have git, so removed this file and other git related files like the `.gitkeep` files in `app/cache` and `app/logs`.

I any case, both the installer and composer always give you a working version of the Symfony Standard Edition.

At last, the build script was [changed](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-installer/issues/73) now the installer became the official way of installing. It'll now contain the git related files. On the other hand, it'll not contain the `LICENSE` file, `UPGRADE-*.md` files and `README.md` file. So in the end, we can say that the one installed by the installer is more usable, as it removes useless files.

Comment: Thanks, great explanation. I've downloaded installer from symfony website so I suppose its bit outdate there, and I just need to update it with latest github version so it will create for me project ready to work with git ? On the other hand I'd like to stay with apache so if i decide to use installer I'll need to worry on my own about finding basic .htaccess files ?

Shame its not configurable through installer parameters.

Answer (score 3):

[Symfony2 Installer](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-installer) will downloaded it from the web site ( in this case: http://symfony.com/download?v=Symfony_Standard_Vendors_2.6.1.zip ).

To see the differences between `symfony installer` and the classic `composer create-project` is enough to take a look at both `composer.lock`: https://www.diffchecker.com/oig86oki

On the left the `composer.lock` generated after `composer create-project`, on the right `symfony installer`. It was obvious to everyone that Symfony2 downloaded from an archive could not have the lastest packages. So, do the update with `composer update`.

Again, on the left the `composer.lock` of `composer create-project`, on the right the new `composer.lock` after the update: https://www.diffchecker.com/lj5j2eap

As we expected. But in the vendor dir there are not the same number of file. Some folders are not there. *Some* folders with functional tests are not downloaded with `symfony installer`. You need to force composer to update all packages, or reinstall them.

Answer (score 1):

Did you update installer as well with :

```
symfony self-update
```

or in windows :

```
php symfony.phar self-update
```

As stated [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-installer) ?

That's perhaps one part of the answer.
Among differences, the installer seems to deal better with different symfony versions.