# Symfony project creation commands

Tags: php, symfony, installation, new-operator

i want to kwow the real difference these two command implicate :

```
 symfony new my_project_name --full
 composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my_project_name
```

anyone could teach me ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Newest symfony installer vs composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27765895/newest-symfony-installer-vs-composer)

Comment: i've already read it, but i would to know if "symfony new" and "composer create-project" are really similar as is explain in the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27765895/newest-symfony-installer-vs-composer thread, or if they implicate a really difference like explained in the symfony doc here https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#creating-symfony-applications but i think i've understood my misunderstanding and it seems to offer the possibility to don't install symfony server when using composer create-project.

Comment: Basically identical as far as Symfony is concerned.  Using the "symfony new" command causes your project to be automatically committed to git.  That is about the only difference I have noticed.  The web server bundle is no longer available under Symfony 5.  The Symfony folks want you to use the installer because the executable is also used to access the Symfony Cloud service.

Answer (score 1):

## Summary

It does doesn't matter which way you go. Both commands will get you to the same place.

## Composer

Composer is a dependency manager.

[composer create-project](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project) is equivalent to:

1. `git clone some/project` which creates a local copy
2. `composer install`  which installs the project's dependencies.

**Composer Example**

Let's say you have the following project:

- /project-folder/

  - hello-script.php
  - composer.json

In the **`hello-script.php`**:

```
<?php
//hello-script.php
require "vendor/autoload.php";

use \Doctrine\Common\Inflector\Inflector;

echo 'hello script';
echo Inflector::ucwords('hello script', '-_ ');
```

In the **`composer.json`** file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "doctrine/inflector": "^1.3"
    }
}
```

To pull down the hello-script dependency `Inflector` you would run:

`composer install`

**Results**

To test you can run `php hello-script.php` on your command line.

```
//Output
hello script
Hello Script
```

## Symfony

Symfony is a framework. It is a suite of tools for generating and serving a web application. The Symfony commands give you the ability to create new projects, serve the projects.